# Does constant exposure to Dengue over a population, increases or decreases the mortality of the epidemic?

Tags: dengue

I'm trying to understand the significantly higher mortality rate of Dengue in Argentina in relation to Brazil. According to this, Argentina in 2024 had 47 deaths out of 57461 cases (1 death each 1222 cases)

[Dengue Argentina 2024- Spanish](https://www.barrons.com/news/spanish/crecieron-2-153-los-casos-de-dengue-en-argentina-en-2024-segun-ministerio-de-salud-0fc93d71)

and Brazil had 41 deaths out of 1658816 (1 death each 40459 cases) .

[Dengue Brazil cases 2023 (Spanish)](https://www.panoramical.eu/america-latina-y-caribe/brasil-podria-duplicar-los-casos-de-dengue-este-ano-respecto-a-2023/)

[Dengue Brazil deaths 2023  - (Spanish)](https://www.france24.com/es/am%C3%A9rica-latina/20240202-brasil-se-prepara-para-enfrentar-una-epidemia-de-dengue-sin-precedentes)

Brazil has had much larger Dengue epidemics for more years, can this has anything to do with it? I understand there are differences in the way statistics are created and gathered in different places, for example, in some places cases are counted by epidemiological link and not by laboratory confirmation, also there might be differences in the way "dengue related deaths" are counted.

But anyway, I wanted to know if there is evidence of exposure to Dengue increasing or decreasing the mortality in a population. It is known exposure to other variant of Dengue significantly increases the chances of severe Dengue, though you get immunity to the same variant

[Dengue in Peru - This is what happens when you get infected a second time (Spanish)](https://www.infobae.com/peru/2024/03/03/dengue-que-pasa-con-un-paciente-si-es-contagiado-por-segunda-vez-con-la-enfermedad/#:%7E:text=Si%20estas%20personas%20se%20llegan,grave%20a%20futuro%E2%80%9D%2C%20manifest%C3%B3.)

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, it is widely thought that there is an increased risk of death or serious harm with subsequent Dengue infections. The WHO has this to say on [their website on Dengue](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/dengue-and-severe-dengue):

> Individuals who are infected for the second time are at greater risk of severe dengue.

<sup>Source. WHO Dengue and Severe Dengue. https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/dengue-and-severe-dengue Website accessed 08 March 2024</sup>

However, there is some debate about the relative frequencies of severe dengue in primary and secondary infection, with some studies finding that there is no such association, at least in the population(s) they studied.<sup>1</sup>, while other analyses found the widely "known" effect of secondary being more likely to cause severe effects. There seems to be some correlation between the serotype of the virus (there are 5 serotypes<sup>2</sup>) and severity of secondary infection<sup>3</sup>.

References:

1. Aggarwal C, Ahmed H, Sharma P, Reddy ES, Nayak K, Singla M, Maheshwari D, Chawla YM, Panda H, Rai RC, Gunisetty S, Priyamvada L, Bhaumik SK, Ahamed SF, Vivek R, Bhatnagar P, Singh P, Kaur M, Dixit K, Kumar S, Gottimukkala K, Saini K, Bajpai P, Sreekanth GP, Mammen S, Rajan A, Verghese VP, Abraham AM, Shah P, Alagarasu K, Yu T, Davis CW, Wrammert J, Ansari A, Antia R, Kabra SK, Medigeshi GR, Ahmed R, Lodha R, Shet A, Chandele A, Murali-Krishna K. Severe disease during both primary and secondary dengue virus infections in pediatric populations. Nat Med. 2024 Feb 6. doi: https://doi.org/10.1038/s41591-024-02798-x. Epub ahead of print. PMID: 38321219.
2. Bhatt P, Sabeena SP, Varma M, Arunkumar G. Current Understanding of the Pathogenesis of Dengue Virus Infection. Curr Microbiol. 2021 Jan;78(1):17-32. doi: https://doi.org/10.1007/s00284-020-02284-w. Epub 2020 Nov 24. PMID: 33231723; PMCID: PMC7815537.
3. Sangkaew S, Ming D, Boonyasiri A, Honeyford K, Kalayanarooj S, Yacoub S, Dorigatti I, Holmes A. Risk predictors of progression to severe disease during the febrile phase of dengue: a systematic review and meta-analysis. Lancet Infect Dis. 2021 Jul;21(7):1014-1026. doi: https://doi.org/10.1016/S1473-3099(20)30601-0. Epub 2021 Feb 25. PMID: 33640077; PMCID: PMC8240557.

Comment: It's hard to understand how it can be that Brazil has 40 times less mortality than Argentina, if the widely "known" effect of secondary infection is true, unless they aren't very strict in their statistics or something. I also always wondered how can they live in Brazil normally, if they have Dengue all the year and millions of cases, if we have much less cases than them and it's distorting our whole lives and we only have it in summer (for now)

Comment: @Pablo There are all sorts of factors at play here, not least accurate gathering and reporting of the statistics. My personal perception (based on not much admittedly) is that Argentina has a better health care system and much less in the way of poor socioeconomic factors than Brazil. These both play a huge role how a country might respond to an epidemic and the statistics etc that are gathered and reported.